# Xml file not updated while download

Tags: angular, spring

I am building an application in which you can add, delete and edit books.

I have option to convert books into xml file and download it.
Problems occurs if i change(add-delete) something in database.
Browser will download only the old file.
If i go to spring console and open booksExport.xml

[image: booksExport.xml created]

changes in file will be visible and i could download it, but until that browser(angular) and spring are not cooperating. like i need some refresh after marshalling.

Angular code

```
downloadXml(data:any){

    const REQUEST_HEADERS = new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/xml' });
    const REQUEST_PARAMS = new HttpParams().set('fileName', data.fileName);
    const REQUEST_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/downloadXml';
    return this.http.get(REQUEST_URI, {
      headers : REQUEST_HEADERS,
      params: REQUEST_PARAMS,
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
```

After request, i use this code

```
@GetMapping(value ="/downloadXml")
public void downloadFile2(String fileName,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
    if(fileName.endsWith(" ")) { fileName =  fileName.substring(0,fileName.length()-1);}
   bookListService.convertBookListToXml(fileName);
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename"+ fileName);
   response.getOutputStream().write(bookListService.writeContentOf(fileName));  
}
```

in spring console i convertBookListToXml from database using marshaller.

```
public void convertBookListToXml(String fileName) throws JAXBException, PropertyException, FileNotFoundException {
    List<BookList> bookList = bookRepository.findAll();
    com.bookstore.senla.model.Books books = new com.bookstore.senla.model.Books();
    books.setBookList(bookList);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.bookstore.senla.model.Books.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(books, new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/"+fileName));
    System.out.println("booksExport.xml is created successfully");
}
```

After creating booksExport.xml
i call service which download file.

```
public byte[] writeContentOf(String fileName) throws Exception{
    System.out.println(Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toURI()));
    return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toURI()));
}
```

Console log is
C:..\target\classes\booksExport.xml

On one hook it generate and download file but the problem is obvious that the target is not refreshed

Can you please give me some recommendation

Comment: You cannot write to the class path and there is no `src/main/resources` when running as jar/war file.

Comment: I add wrong service function,  i correct the question

Comment: Regardless, you cannot write to the classpath.Also why the intermediate writing to file, just directly write the output to the outputstream instead of creating a file.